# TFS show iteration Start and End Date on PBI

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, iteration, tfs-process-template

I use TFS 2012 with the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.2 process template. I would like to see the iteration start and end date a Product Backlog item (PBI) is associated to on the PBI form itself?

If it's possible what fields do I need to refer to in the Work Item type definition?

If it's not possible, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the dates right in the Iteration names.  So instead of "Iteration 1" you could call it "I1 - Oct 1-20"

Comment: Indeed that would be a way to go. But I work in a bigger company with some collections a lot of team projects and uncountable iterations. I can't and won't change all those. Could I access the iteration dates by event customizing?

Comment: Not really. Dylan has the only solution.

Comment: Even though its not the solution I looking for I mark it as answer. It seems what I need is not possible.